# Changing the format of jQuery UI's datepicker breaks synchronisation with a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Thanks to techfoobar, I have a datepicker with a synchronised input field and a select list.

However, when I have changed the format of the date to "yy-mm-dd", it stopped working. A change in the select list triggers the change in the input, but clicking the datepicker won't update the select list.

Here is the script:

```
$(function() {
        $('#selectedDatepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShow: readSelected, onSelect: updateSelected,
    minDate: new Date(2013, 1 - 1, 1), maxDate: new Date(2013, 06 - 1, 31),
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    showOn: 'both', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif'});

// Prepare to show a date picker linked to three select controls
function readSelected() {
    $('#selectedDatepicker').val($('#selectYear').val() + '-' +
        $('#selectDay').val());
    return {};
}

// Update three select controls to match a date picker selection
function updateSelected() {
    var date1 = $(this).val();

    console.log(date1.substring(3, 5));
    console.log(date1.substring(6, 10));

    $('#selectDay').val(date1.substring(3, 5));
    $('#selectYear').val(date1.substring(6, 10));
}

    $('select').change(readSelected);

    });
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<select id="selectDay">
<option value="01">1</option>
<option value="02">2</option>
<option value="03">3</option>
<option value="04">4</option>
...
</select>
<select id="selectYear">
<option value="2013-01">January 2013</option>
<option value="2013-02">February 2013</option>
<option value="2013-03">March 2013</option>
<option value="2013-04">April 2013</option>
<option value="2013-05">May 2013</option>
<option value="2013-06">June 2013</option>
</select>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="selectedDatepicker" /></p>
```

You can check the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xKXZm/8/

Where does this problem come from? Both of the fields have the same format set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are trying to select in the select element does not exist, because the substring yields a different value than it originally did. You need to adjust your `substr` accordingly.

```
function updateSelected() {
    var date1 = $(this).val();

    console.log(date1.substring(8));
    console.log(date1.substring(0, 4));

    $('#selectDay').val(date1.substring(8));
    $('#selectYear').val(date1.substring(0, 7));
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xKXZm/10/)

Comment: also will need to pad zeros for 1-9 or remove leading zeros from option values

Comment: @charlietfl They're strings, so it shouldn't really make a difference, should it? It's working in the fiddle for dates < 10.

Comment: try it ... I did and had to pad leading zero

Comment: I just did, seems to be working as is. What dates in particular does this fail for?

Comment: I only tried hardcoding `$(select).val('5')` and wouldn't work without "05".

Comment: That is because his options have values `'01','02','03','04','05'` etc. `'5' != '05'` The string returned by the datepicker already has a leading zero.

Comment: interesting it works in fiddle with datepicker but not hardcoding the string as value

Comment: Dude it still works if you hard code it, you just have to hard code `'05'`, not `'5'`. `date1.substring(8)` returns `'05'`

Comment: OK... I hadn't looked to see that `date1.substring(8)` has leading zero...my bad